# Can I use multiple AirPods Max with Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, airpods

Can I connect more than one set of AirPods Max to an Apple TV?  My wife and I would both like to watch Apple TV using APMs for audio.

Both APMs need to support full functionality, ie, spatial audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from Apple TV User Guide:

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/tv/atvb50fb1c50/14.0/tvos/14.0

> [image: Share audio from Apple TV 4K with a second pair of headphones]

According to this guide, audio sharing via Apple wireless headphones is supported on Apple TV 4K running tvOS 14 or later.

Comment: As an FYI, the Apple Genius Bar in Knoxville, TN said that it is undocumented but Apple TV 4K supports from 3 to 6 AirPods Max.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply go to the settings app on your AppleTV and go down to "Devices"

You should then be able to pair a new Bluetooth device. Simply hold the button on the back of your Airpods Max's until the status light on the side is blinking white. Then wait for the TV to find the device.

If the TV fails to find the device, restart the TV by unplugging it and plugging it back in. Then reset the Airpods by holding the pairing button until it turns orange, then white again.